# Search script doesn't look for individual words

Tags: javascript, search

I am using the script below for my HTML sites search.

The problem I have is that it searches for the words together as one phrase when I want it to search for the words independently throughout the XML. i.e. if someone enters "Digital producer" it searches for "Digital producer", not the words "Digital" and "producer" separately.

Any help on getting this to work would be greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//GLOBAL VAR
var XMLSource = $('#data').attr('xmlData');
var keyword = '';
var catType = '';
var pub = '';

var i = 0;

$("#searchButton").click(function() {
    keyword = $("input#term").val();
    catType = $("#category option:selected").val();

    //Reset any message
    var errMsg = '';
    pub = '';

    if ( keyword == '' ) { errMsg += 'Please Enter Search Term' + '\n'; }
    else if ( catType == 'none' ) { errMsg += 'Please Select Category' + '\n'; }
    else { searchThis(); }

    if ( errMsg != '' ) {
        pub += '<div class="error">' + '\n';
        pub += errMsg;
        pub += '</div>' + '\n';
    }

    //Show error
    $('#result').html( pub );

});

function searchThis() {             
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XMLSource,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) { loadPublication (xml) }    
    });
}

function loadPublication (xmlData) {
    i = 0;
    var row;

    var searchExp = "";

    $(xmlData).find('Job').each(function(){

        var SearchTitle = $(this).find('SearchTitle').text();
        var Description = $(this).find('Description').text();
        var EmailTo = $(this).find('EmailTo').text();

        //Format the keyword expression
        var exp = new RegExp(keyword,"gi");

        //Check if there is a category selected; 
        //if not, use EmailTo column as a default search
        if ( catType == 'SearchTitle' ) { searchExp = SearchTitle.match(exp); }
        else if ( catType == 'Description' ) { searchExp = Description.match(exp); }
        else if ( catType == 'EmailTo' ) { searchExp = EmailTo.match(exp); }

        if ( searchExp != null ) {

            //Start building the result
            if ((i % 2) == 0) { row = 'even'; }
            else { row = 'odd'; }

            i++;                

            pub += '<tr class="row ' + row + '">' + '\n';
            pub += '<td valign="top" class="col1">' + SearchTitle + '</td>' + '\n'; 
            pub += '<td valign="top" class="col2">' + Description + '</td>' + '\n'; 
            pub += '<td valign="top" class="col3">' + EmailTo + '</td>' + '\n'; 
            pub += '</tr>' + '\n';
        }   
    });

    if ( i == 0 ) {
        pub += '<div class="error">' + '\n';
        pub += 'No Result Found' + '\n';    
        pub += '</div>' + '\n';

        //Populate the result
        $('#result').html( pub );
    }
    else {
        //Pass the result set
        showResult ( pub );
    }
}

function showResult (resultSet) {

    //Show the result
    pub = '<table id="grid" border="0">' + '\n';
    pub += '<thead><tr>' + '\n';
    pub += '<th class="col1">Job Title</th>' + '\n';
    pub += '<th class="col2">Job Description</th>' + '\n';
    pub += '<th class="col3">Apply To</th>' + '\n';
    pub += '</tr></thead>' + '\n';
    pub += '<tbody>' + '\n';

    pub += resultSet;

    pub += '</tbody>' + '\n';
    pub += '</table>' + '\n';

    //Populate 
    $('#result').html(pub)

    $('#grid').tablesorter(); 
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using regular expressions, what you can do is replace all the spaces in your original search string with an the OR operator `|` (<- it's a pipe [ shift + \ ] in case it's hard to tell). You can do this adding the line `keyword = keyword.replace(" ", "|");` right before `var exp = new RegExp(keyword,"gi");`

Let me know if this works for you and if it makes sense :)

Some references:
JavaScript Replace - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp
RegExp Operators - http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/72regular/